# Consulta sobre 2 listas en python y matematicas

Tags: python

Tengo 2 listas

```
lista1 = ["R1","R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6"]
lista2 = ["Frase 1","Frase 2","Frase 3","Frase 4","Frase 5","Frase 6"]
```

Desearía que TODOS los 'Rx' de la lista1 se combinen con TODOS los de la lista2. No de manera secuencial, sino aleatorio. Por ejemplo:

- R1 con Frase 3
- R1 con Frase 4
- etc

De la misma manera, los otros R, pero comprobando que ningún R duplicaría su combinación. Si tengo 6 Rs y 6 frases la combinación sería 6 x 6 = 36.
¿Alguien me ayuda por favor?

Comment: No entiendo, ¿tu combinación debe resultar de 6 o de 36 resultados? ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con que *ningún R duplicaría su combinación*?

Comment: La combincion final serian 36. R1 ebe hacer Lista1,2,3,4,5,6 pero no secuencial, o sea 2,4,3,6,1,5 y comprobar en ese paso aleatorio que no repita nadie, e decir si paso por R1 y hace Lista2, y despues paso por R4 y hace Lista5, cuando vuelva a R1 "saber" que ya hizo Lista2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que quieres son todas las combinaciones posibles puedes usar el producto cartesiano de ambas listas usando [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lista1 = ["R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6"]
>>> lista2 = ["Frase 1", "Frase 2", "Frase 3", "Frase 4", "Frase 5", "Frase 6"]
>>> combinaciones = list(itertools.product(lista1, lista2))
>>> len(combinaciones)
36
>>> combinaciones
[('R1', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 6')]
```

Si quieres escoger una combinación al azar puedes usar [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(combinaciones)
('R2', 'Frase 6')
>>> random.choice(combinaciones)
('R6', 'Frase 4')
>>> random.choice(combinaciones)
('R4', 'Frase 2')
```

### Actualización

Es cierto que al usar `random.choice` es posible que en algún momento se repita alguna. En ese caso una solución puede ser aplicar un [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) e ir consumiento los elementos desde el principio hasta el final:

```
>>> random.shuffle(combinaciones)
>>> combinaciones
[('R6', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R4', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 5'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R1', 'Frase 6'),
 ('R6', 'Frase 3'),
 ('R2', 'Frase 2'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 1'),
 ('R5', 'Frase 4'),
 ('R3', 'Frase 5')]
```

La variable `combinaciones` es una **lista de tuplas**, para acceder a Rx y FraseX solo tienes que acceder a la posición `0` y `1` de cada tupla. Considerando la lista "shuffleada" de arriba:

```
>>> rx = combinaciones[0][0]
>>> rx
'R6'
>>> frase = combinaciones[0][1]
>>> frase
'Frase 4'
```

O descargando el contenido directamente en dos variables:

```
>>> rx, frase = combinaciones[0]
>>> rx
'R6'
>>> frase
'Frase 4'
```

Comment: Ok excelente, para pasar por TODA la lista y no secuencial podria hacer un shuffle (combinaciones) ? Y asi ser siempre aleatorio ?

Comment: @papabomay en realidad `random.choice` ya escoge uno aleatoriamente

Comment: Si pero en realidad si hago varios random.choice existe la posibilidad de repetir... no ? Quiero que haga todos sin repetir, y perdon mi ignorancia, como accedo a Rx por un lado y a FraseX por otro lado, , la estructura es una lista de listas ? Ahi me perdi ...

Comment: Entiendo, dejame actualizar mi respuesta @papabomay

Comment: Perfecto, y excelente respuesta, sumamente útil ! Muy bien Cesar !

Comment: @papabomay de nada! Ya la actualicé

Comment: AWESOME !!....nuevamente gracias !